# setting locale for utf-8 , but to keep measurements, time, date, etc .like with ="C"?

Tags: locale, unicode

End goal: use utf-8, but keep rest default (i.e. monetary, date, numeric, etc formats).

I come up with idea "let's make system utf-8 , but keep measurements, time, date, etc like it was" and this (probably terrible) implementation:

```
LANG="en_US.utf-8"  # or en_GB.utf-8
LANGUAGE="en_US.utf-8"  # or en_GB.utf-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
```

It seems intuitively (and in practice), that "C" (which is non utf-8, right?) will not mix well with ".utf-8" locales (and it does not! quiet often some encoding dragon jumps out).

What is recommended ".utf-8" locale (which I should use in "=C" cases) to preserve spirit of original units, measurements (km not miles, Celsius not Fahrenheit etc), date&time format, paper (actually I'd like A4, not "letter"), etc?

( or maybe "C" locale can be mixed with ".utf-8" locale, and I made other mistake ? )

Comment: Some systems have a C.UTF-8 locale for something like that. The C locale has a single-byte charset usually ASCII with bytes 128 to 255 undefined, not UTF-8

Comment: Just changing `LC_CTYPE` would affect the character encoding without changing the regional settings.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/open-infrastructure-locales-c.utf-8/locales-c.utf-8.7.en.html#RATIONAL explains the **what** and **why** of **C.UTF-8**. In short: prevent programs from failing to start or output warnings on the command line. Target: servers. Saves 125MiB over locales-all and 10MiB over locale.

Comment: What you are suggesting is perfectly valid.